# bitbake way to add a system.conf setting

Tags: yocto, systemd, bitbake

I am trying to find a bitbake way to add a `/etc/systemd/system.conf` setting (in my case "DisableControllers=cpu") into the `[Manager]` - currently the system.conf file is just filled with commented out parameters (i.e. nothing is set).

I have not found anything like `SYSTEMD_CONF:append` to do this, so I guess I have to just do something like:

#### systemd_%.bbappend

```
do_install:append() {
    echo "DisableControllers=cpu" >> ${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system.conf
}
```

I can't think of a nicer way to do that - and this looks like its a bit hacky

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. systemd is specifically off topic. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or https://superuser.com/

Comment: @rob Isn't bitbake considered programmatic? - above is a function/code snippet for example. The answer below only added variable assignments - but which are used in functions and so on.... Not saying you are wrong, but its a bit grey in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe that installs `system.conf` is `poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-conf_1.0.bb`. You can also accomplish this by overriding the system.conf that gets installed to rootfs from your own layer.

1. Add your custom `system.conf` file in your layer at `recipes-core/systemd/systemd-conf/system.conf`
2. Create an append file for the original recipe in your layer at `poky/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd-conf_%.bbappend`
3. And add the following line to the append file you created

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
```

As long as your layer has priority over poky (it's priority is 5) something like this should do the trick.

Edit: If there are other layers that are fiddling with systemd-conf your layers priority needs to be higher than theirs as well.